# Have the server build VS. check in & push a locally built app

Tags: node.js, git, heroku, webpack, web-deployment

What are some pro/cons to pushing built code vs. having the server build it?

This is a general question, but here's my specific scenario to illustrate what I'm talking about:
On Heroku I've got a React app that has a simple express server to do OAuth. Currently, I have a postinstall hook in my package.json that runs a webpack production config to do some extract-text stuff and create a dist/ directory with my bundled, uglifyied code. To get all of this to run on Heroku I had to mark pretty much all of my dependencies as 'dependencies' instead of 'devDependencies'.

I know it's a bad practice to check my dist/ into git but it would save me from having to install a dozen plus node_modules on the server. Any thoughts?